# Folland Proposition 1.4 Generating product sigma algebra from generators of measures

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, measure-theory

In the following proposition from Folland Real Analysis, why is $\left\{E \subset X_{\alpha}: \pi_{\alpha}^{-1}(E) \in \mathcal{M}\left(\mathcal{F}_{1}\right)\right\}$ seen to be a $\sigma$-algebra? The author leaves this unjustified and I don't see it myself after some thought.

**1.4 Proposition.** Suppose that $M_{\alpha}$ is generated by $\varepsilon_{\alpha,} \alpha \in A$. Then $\otimes_{\alpha \in A}$ $\mathcal{M}_\alpha$ is generated by $\mathcal{F}_{1}=\left\{\pi_{\alpha}^{-1}\left(E_{\alpha}\right): E_{\alpha} \in \mathcal{E}_{\alpha}, \alpha \in A\right\}$.

Proof. Obviously $\mathcal{M}\left(\mathcal{F}_{1}\right) \subset \bigotimes_{\alpha \in A} \mathcal{M}_{\alpha}$. On the other hand, for each $\alpha$, the collection $\left\{E \subset X_{\alpha}: \pi_{\alpha}^{-1}(E) \in \mathcal{M}\left(\mathcal{F}_{1}\right)\right\}$ is easily seen to be a $\sigma$ -algebra on $X_{\alpha}$ that contains $\varepsilon_\alpha$ and hence $\mathcal{M}_\alpha$. In other words, $\pi_\alpha^{-1}(E)\in \mathcal{M}(\mathcal{F}_1)$ for all $E\in \mathcal{M}_\alpha$
$\alpha \in A$, and hence $ \bigotimes_{\alpha \in A}\mathcal{M}_\alpha  \subset \mathcal{M}\left(\mathcal{F}_{1}\right)$

Comment: Have you tried proving this is a sigma-algebra? Did you get stuck?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $S=\left\{E \subset X_{\alpha}: \pi_{\alpha}^{-1}(E) \in \mathcal{M}\left(\mathcal{F}_{1}\right)\right\}$ then we need $S$ to be closed under compliments and countable unions. If $E \in S$ then $\pi_{\alpha}^{-1}(E) \in \mathcal{M}\left(\mathcal{F}_{1}\right)$. But $\mathcal{M}\left(\mathcal{F}_{1}\right)$ is a $\sigma$-algebra so $\pi_{\alpha}^{-1}(E)^c = \pi_{\alpha}^{-1}(E^c)  \in \mathcal{M}\left(\mathcal{F}_{1}\right)$. This shows that $E^c \in S$. You can make a similar argument to show closure under countable unions.